# OpenGL and displaying a grey scale image

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying to display a grey scale image using OpenGL. I know almost 0 on OpenGL and basically using an example I found online. Below is the modified code I am trying to make work. I am essentially setting the Grey value (0 to 255) for a 100x100 image, so expecting an all white/black/grey image.

However it is my understanding OpenGL expects the input data to be RGB, so it has to be 24 bits (assuming 8 bits per channel). I am only working with 8 bit images. I have tried the different parameters for input (GL_ALPHA/GL_RED) from the docs http://docs.gl/gl4/glTexImage2D

Is there anyway I can make an 8 bit image like this work?

```
int image_width = 100;
int image_height = 100;
unsigned char image_data[image_width * image_height];
// Force the grey value for all pixels
for (int i = 0; i < image_height * image_width; i++) {
  image_data[i] = 255;
}
// Create a OpenGL texture identifier
GLuint image_texture;
glGenTextures(1, &image_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image_texture);

// Setup filtering parameters for display
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// Upload pixels into texture
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, image_width, image_height, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
```

Comment: "However it is my understanding OpenGL expects the input data to be RGB, so it has to be 24 bits (assuming 8 bits per channel)." That is not true at all. However, the situation is much more complex - that data formats you use in client memory, the internal forrmat of the texture, and the shaders all play a role here. OpenGL is a render API, not an image drawing library, so if you want to use it for that purpose, you will have to learn a lot of the basics, first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context), you can use `GL_LUMINANCE`, where each element is a single luminance value. See [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml).

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, image_width, image_height, 0,
             GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
```